# iPhone: How do I share information between my UITabBarViewController and the individual Tabs?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `TableViewController` that segues into a `TabBarViewController`.

I know how to pass my object via a segue, but not by a relationship like the `TabBarViewController` and it's tab share.

How can I do this?  **From the TabView is there a way to access the TabBarViewControllers member variables?**

Update:

This is how I've solved the problem so far, but I'm not crazy about using the AppDelegate to do this...

Add the Following to `WhateverYouNamedYourAppDelegate.h`

```
@class myObjectIWantToPass;
@property (strong, nonatomic) myObjectIWantToPass *object;
```

Then add the following to the View Class file you have your data in that you want to pass on. I'm going to assume you know how to set up your object already in this file if your planning on passing it to another view.

```
WhateverYouNamedYourAppDelegate *appDelegate = 
(WhateverYouNamedYourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.object = object;
```

Then you do some similar work to retrieve the object back from the appDelegate in your destination View Class.

```
WhateverYouNamedYourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (WhateverYouNamedYourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
object = appDelegate.object;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make singleton classes, so that all of the controllers can access those variables in the Singleton. See Code below

SingletonClass.h

```
@interface SingletonClass : NSObject {
    NSString *someString;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *someString;

+(id)shared;

@end
```

SingletonClass.m

```
#import "SingletonClass.h"

static SingletonClass *aShared;

@implementation LibShared
@synthesize someString;

+(id)shared
{
    if (aShared == nil) {
    aShared = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return aShared;
}

-(id)init
{
   if (self = [super init]) {

   }
}

-(void)dealloc
{
  [someString releease];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

In the tabbar you can set the variable on SingletonClass:

```
[[SingletonClass shared] setSomeString:@"Value_Set"];
```

On the tableViewController, you can get the property of the someString variable on the SingletonClass:

```
NSString *string =  [[SingletonClass shared] someString];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I want to great a class such as that to pass information from one view to another... there has to be a better way yes?  My problem is I'm passing the information from one view to another with a segue, but from my tabbar view to the individual tabs there are no segues so i can't pass it the same way.

Comment: A singleton is your best bet. Apple does it too, with NSUserDefaults for example. It's meant for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a singleton pattern here.  Instead, you can send the data-object forwards in `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` just as you do normally, you just need to find the correct viewController in the `UITabBarController`'s `viewControllers` property.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MyTabBarSegue]) {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController;

        // Either set the index here, if you know for sure which viewController is which, or
        // Enumerate the viewControllers for isKindOfClass:[MYCustomViewController class] to be robust and change-proof
        MYCustomViewController *myVC = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        myVC.dataObject = self.dataObject;
    }
}
```